# Вывод элемента QByteArray в QLineEdit и QPlainText

Tags: c++, qt

Через последовательный порт приходит массив данных, который записывается в QByteArray. Мне нужно взять конкретный байт из этого массива, допустим arr[5], перевести его в десятичное представление и вывести в QLineEdit и QPlainText.

Пробовал следующие варианты:

`ui->console->insertPlainText("Принято: " + arr.at(5).toDec + '\r');`

`ui->console->insertPlainText("Принято: " + arr[5].toDec + '\r');`

`ui->dataSize->setText(static_cast<QString>(arr.at(5)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[5]` - выражение типа `char`. Преобразовать его ч число: `int(arr[5])`. Число в строку (вам, ведъ, нужен QString?): `QString::number(int(arr[5])` см. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number

Или, раз уж мы в Qt, то можно использовать подстановку аргументов в строки, для прощения локализации: `tr("Принято: %1").arg(int(arr[5]))`  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-5